# XSS issues: jsp and request parameters

Tags: jsp, xss

I am not good in xss, and I wanted to ask if it is safe to have this in jsp page:

```
<jsp:forward page="<%=somePage%>" />
```

where `somePage` can contain input from request parameters, e.g. `test='XSS'`?

then the link will look like `myjsp.jsp?test=XSS`

Thank you.

Comment: How many JSPs do you have? What is the flow? Where is the above code written?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not safe at all. You're basically letting the end user choose where to forward. The end user could for example pass `/WEB-INF/web.xml`, and they would get the web.xml file, which is not supposed to be public.